# Jquery Modify background position from existing for each class instance?

Tags: jquery, css, parallax, background-position

I am creating a parallax on a page that is modifying background positions and what I have works as long as I want all the backgrounds to start at zero. The problem is I don't want them all to start at zero. Some have predetermined start positions but I can't figure out how to increase/decrease each class instance's background position from it's existing position. You can see in my code I have a line that can retrieve the current position, but every time I try to use that number to modify position I get crazy results where the image flies all over everywhere. Here's what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        currentoffset = $(this).scrollTop();
        slowOff = Number(currentoffset) / 3;

        $( ".full_width_img" ).each(function() {
            //bgPosition = $(this).css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
            $(this).css('background-position', '50% -' + slowOff + "px");
        });
    });
});
```

How can I retrieve then update each instance's background-position property relative to each individual's existing position?

added jfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/79k8R/

Comment: can you put up a demo?

Comment: I'm trying to pull this off: http://www.gamesradar.com/lightning-returns-final-fantasy-xiii-review/

Comment: I understand the effect you're going for but I meant a "what I have so far" demo on jsfiddle or something that people could hack on to help you. I don't know any obvious way to solve your problem and I'm not inclined to recreate it all to try to help. But if it was already in a fiddle...

Comment: added link to the post for jfiddle

Comment: I don't have a solution, but as far as I know you can't use a mixture of % and px to e.g. set a position :)

Comment: I tried to make a -= work, but that did not. Atleast the way i was doing it. Maybe I'm supposed to be doing something that only triggers when it's on screen or something....

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical mistake here. In the "each" loop, you might have to adjust the background position (Y) for each image. I have added (slowOff-240*index) instead of just "showOff", which looks better. But you can always adjust this based on your need to make it beautiful. Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LZhAL/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        currentoffset = $(this).scrollTop();
        slowOff = Number(currentoffset) / 3;

        $( ".full_width_img" ).each(function(index) {
            //bgPosition = $(this).css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
            $(this).css('background-position', '50% -' + (slowOff-240*index) + "px");
        });
    });
});
```